# What is the expected number of steps before the spider exits? Markov Chain

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chain

A little spider lives in a rectangular box of which the sides are 3 and 4 cm long. It can only sit in one of the four corners marked with the numbers 1,2,3,4 (clockwise). Assume in Corner 2 there is a bigger spider ready to eat the little spider and in Corner 3 there is a hole leading to the outside through which the spider can escape. If the spider in Corner 1, what is the expected number of steps before the spider exists?

Here is the Markov chain transition matrix

$${\begin{bmatrix}
     0 & 15/47 & 12/47 & 20/47\\
     15/47 & 0 & 20/47 & 12/47\\
     12/47 & 20/47 & 0 & 15/47\\
     20/47 & 12/47 & 15/47 & 0
\end{bmatrix}}_{4\times 4}$$

In my notes my lecturer says we have to solve

```
e1 = 15/47+12/47+20/47(1+e4)
e2 = 20/47+15/47(1+e1)+12/47(1+e4)
e3 = 20/47+12/47(1+e1)+15/47(1+e4)
e4 = 12/47+15/47+20/47(1+e1)
```

I don't really understand. Anyone can explain why?

Comment: The spider exists at the start. Did you mean 'exits' instead?

Comment: Yes. Typo error. I change it now. Thank you very much

Comment: You have asked your question well, but if you still feel uncertain about how this forum works, you might like to read our [help] for more information.

Comment: I'm confused about this problem set up. It sounds like if the spider reaches corner 2 or corner 3, the chain is over. So why are there valid transition probabilities from these two sstates to the other states? If the spider reaches corner two or three, for all intents and purposes doesn't it "stay" there? If not, the next state after two should always be "dead" and the next state after three should always be "exited," but it looks like these states aren't represented in your transition matrix since it's 4x4 and not 6x6.

Comment: At present, this question is NARQ.